# Why do I have "join: extra operand '/dev/fd/62'" error?

Tags: text-processing, join, coreutils

I have a script `equijoin2`:

```
#! /bin/bash

# default args                                                                                                                                                                    
delim="," # CSV by default                                                                                                                                                        
outer=""
outerfile=""
# Parse flagged arguments:                                                                                                                                                        
while getopts "o:td:" flag
do
  case $flag in
    d) delim=$OPTARG;;
    t) delim="\t";;
    o) outer="-a $OPTARG";;
    ?) exit;;
  esac
done
# Delete the flagged arguments:                                                                                                                                                   
shift $(($OPTIND -1))
# two input files                                                                                                                                                                 
f1="$1"
f2="$2"
# cols from the input files                                                                                                                                                       
col1="$3"
col2="$4"


join "$outer" -t "$delim" -1 "$col1" -2 "$col2" <(sort "$f1") <(sort "$f2")
```

and two files

```
$ cat file1
c c1
b b1
$ cat file2
a a2
c c2
b b2
```

Why does the last command fail? Thanks.

```
$ equijoin2 -o 2  -d " " file1 file2 1 1
a a2
b b1 b2
c c1 c2
$ equijoin2 -o 1  -d " " file1 file2 1 1
b b1 b2
c c1 c2
$ equijoin2   -d " " file1 file2 1 1
join: extra operand '/dev/fd/62'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"$outer"` is a quoted scalar variable so it always expands to one argument. If empty or unset, that still expands to one empty argument to `join` (and when you call your script with `-o2`, that's one `-a 2` argument instead of the two arguments `-a` and `2`).

Your `join` is probably GNU `join` in that it accepts options after non-option arguments. That `"$outer"` is a non-option argument when empty as it doesn't start with `-` so is treated as a file name and `join` complains about the third file name provided which it doesn't expect.

If you want a variable with a variable number of arguments, use an array:

```
outer=()
...
(o)
   outer=(-a "$OPTARG");;

...
join "${outer[@]}"
```

Though here you could also do:

```
outer=
...
(o)
   outer="-a$OPTARG";;
...
join ${outer:+"$outer"} ... <(sort < "$f1") <(sort < "$f2")
```

Or:

```
unset -v outer
...
(o)
   outer="$OPTARG";;
...
join ${outer+-a "$outer"} ...
```

(that one doesn't work in `zsh` except in sh/ksh emulation).

Some other notes:

- `join -t '\t'` doesn't work. You'd need `delim=$'\t'` to  store a literal TAB in `$delim`
- Remember to use `--` when passing arbitrary arguments to commands (or use redirections where possible). So `sort -- "$f1"` or better `sort < "$f1"` instead of `sort "$f1"`.
- arithmetic expansions are also subject to split+glob so should also be quoted (`shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"`) (here not a problem though as you're using `bash` which doesn't inherit `$IFS` from the environment and you're not modifying `IFS` earlier in the script, but still good practice).

Comment: Thanks. For `sort -t '\t'`, (1)  does it also apply to `join -t `? (2) coreutils manual doesn't mention that or I miss it. The manual says "To specify ASCII NUL as the fi eld separator, use the two-character string‘ \0’, e.g., ‘sort -t ’\0’’." Is `\t '\0'` an exception?

Comment: @Tim, my bad, I meant `join -t`, not `sort -t`. `join -t '\0'` is a GNU extension. Generally, other implementations of text utilities can't cope with NUL bytes as that's not text. NUL is the one byte that can't be passed as argument to an _executed_ command, so it has to be represented by some form of encoding.

Comment: @Tim, that's not `bash`, that's GNU join which chooses to understand `\0` as the NUL byte. `bash`'s `$'\0'` actually expands to the empty string, not a NUL byte. `zsh`'s `$'\0'` expands to a NUL byte but only works for builtins or functions. A NUL byte can't be passed as argument to a command that is _executed_ because the list of argument passed to  the `execve()` system call is a list of NUL-delimited strings.

Comment: Sorry deleted the comment. But please keep your reply. The reason I asked if it is bash's ANSI C quoting is "sort won’t accept ‘\t’, since it treats it as a multi-byte character. The solution is to place a $ before it. The dollar sign tells bash to use ANSI-C quoting" https://robfelty.com/2008/07/14/sort-using-tab-as-field-separator-in-bash  Is it wrong?

Comment: "`join -t '\0'` is a GNU extension". Do you mean the GNU extension allows just for `join -t '\0'` or also for other such as `join -t '\t'`?

Comment: `bash` expands `$'\t'` to a TAB character. `'\t'` passes a string of two characters `\ ` and `t`. The point is that you need to pass the character as-is to `join -t`, you can also do `join -t '<literal-tab-here-entered-with-Ctrl-V-tab-for-instance>'` or `join -t "$(printf '\t')"`, but obviously that can't be done for the NUL character as a NUL character can never be passed in an argument, that's a limitation of the `execve()` system call.

Comment: Another question "when you call your script with `-o 2`, that's one `-a 2` argument" to `join`, and why does that one `-a 2` argument still work for `join` in the same way as `-a` and `2` two arguments for `join`? See the last three examples in my post.

Comment: @Tim, because `join '-a 2'` is like `join -a ' 2'` and when `join` parses `' 2'` to extract the number, it skips and ignores the leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks. Which provides the way of typing tab by Ctrl-V-tab: bash's readline or terminal emulator or X window system? More at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/458242/674