# What are different ways to type in a literal character in Bash and how are they done?

Tags: bash

In Bash, to type in a literal TAB character:

- hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> key doesn't work but will only invoke completion of readline used by Bash
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> works
- `$(echo $'\t')` works

#### Questions

- Is it correct that the third way is actually done by Bash interpreting `$'\t'` as an ANSI C string for the tab character?
- How is the second way done? Also by readline used by Bash?
- Generally  what are some ways to type in a literal character?

Originated from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458074/674

Answer (score 2):

### How it's made

The so called by you "literal characters" are implemented as ordinary Unicode charachters. Let's look how it works for `Tabulation` and `New line`. Check `Tabulation` hex-encoding:

```
printf $'\t' | hexdump
```

The output is

```
0000000 0009                                   
0000001
```

The output means the `\t` character is ordinary UTF-8 character `U+0009`. You can print it in such the way:

```
printf '\x00\x09'
```

or with `echo`:

```
echo -e '\u0009'
```

Consider the following example for `New line` character:

```
bob@alice:~$ printf $'\n' | hexdump
0000000 000a                                   
0000001
bob@alice:~$ printf '\x00\x0A empty lines are above and below'; echo $'\n'

 empty lines are above and below

bob@alice:~$ echo -e '\u000a empty line is above'

 empty line is above
bob@alice:~$
```

### How to input Unicode characters

There is so called `ComposeKey` or `MultiKey` in Linux. The key can be defined in `xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.conf` file, just add the line to file:

```
Option "xkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,compose:menu"`
```

UTF-8 (Unicode) compose sequence hints can be found in `Compose` file:

```
less /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
```

In GUI terminals also works `CTRL+SHIFT+U` keybinding - press it and you'll see `u` letter. Input `266a` and complete it with `Space` or `Enter` key - the Eights Note sign appears.

### Additional information

1. [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)
2. [Ubuntu - ComposeKey](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey)
3. [Wikipedia - Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key)
4. [How to set a Compose Key in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028957/how-to-set-a-compose-key-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: TAB is encoded as one 0x09 byte in ASCII or UTF-8, not two 0x00 and 0x09 bytes. See the second address in hexdump output  is 1 meaning there was only one byte. `hexdump` dumps 16bit words by default. Use `od -vtx1` instead. It would only be encoded as 0009 in UTF-16BE, an encoding that is not Unix-compatible.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for your remark. Please, pay your attention I have avoided intentionally to use UTF-8 encoded characters and used encoding independent Unicode **Code Point** `U+0009` for Unicode tabulation **control code**. I didn't use intentionally a "byte-language". Take into account, using of `\x00` isn't a mistake too since according to part 23.1 of **Unicode Standard** v.11  usage of `U+0000` is outside the scope of the Unicode Standard, which does not require any particular usage of null (page 858). Read: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode11.0.0/UnicodeStandard-11.0.pdf